# Blowfish Algorithm in PHP and iOS

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, encryption, crypt

I'm trying to encrypt a string the same way on a server in PHP as on an Objective-C on iOS. I've used PHP's crypt() function with the blowfish algorithm, but it takes two parameters: the string to encode and a salt. The Objective-C implementation I found: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28430840/Blowfish-iOS-Source.zip
which was at http://www.codeding.com/articles/blowfish-encryption-algorithm-for-iphone takes three different parameters: either EBC/CBC encoding, an initvector and a key -- how does this translate to the PHP salt?

I found the initial c library but I have no idea how to include it in my project -- when I compile it fails and complains about the x86.S file.

Thanks!!!

Comment: You are confusing two unrelated concepts. bcrypt is not an encryption algorithm; it is a key derivation function typically used for password hashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are looking at the wrong function. It's not `crypt` what you search, but [`mcrypt_encrypt`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php).

This function takes an init vector, a key and an encoding parameter.

Comment: One last question! Whats the difference between ECB and CBC? Is either better?

Comment: @NickC have a look at this comment: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php#78543